# Titanium.Contacts.Person.fullName is showing as "No Name"

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm working on updating an app that's a few years old, and it had to be bumped from an older titanium SDK to 3.5.0 and an exacting contacts picker is no longer functioning.

```
var params = {
    fields:["phone"]
};

params.selectedProperty = function (e) {

        var teamMember = new CoachesApp.Joli.record(App.Models.TeamMemberModel);
        teamMember.fromArray({
            team_id:_teamEntity.team_id,
            record_id:e.person.recordId,
            person_name:e.person.fullName,
            person_label:e.label,
            person_property:e.property
        });

        teamMember.save();

        _refreshTeamMembersData();
        _checkForNoResults();

    };
```

That grabs from iOS simulator

```
{"value":"888-555-1212","property":"phone","label":"home","type":"selectedProperty","source":{},"person":{}}
```

and person_name ends up being "No Name" rather than the real name. Turns out, person is showing as `[object TiContactsPerson]` but none of the values are actually there.

Any ideas?